# Interior points in the induced topology And the map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/G$ when $G$ acts PD upon $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

For, $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$,  $a,b$ are not interior points. However if I observe $([a,b] ,\{U\cap [a,b] : U\in \mathcal{T_\mathbb{R}}\})$ then if I understand correctly $a,b$ are interior points of $[a,b]$ as a space with the induced topology.

My confusion arises from the next problem - if $G$ acts PD upon Hausdorff, path connected and locally path connected space then $p:X\overset{p(x)=O(x)}\longrightarrow X / G $  is a regular covering space. Another theorem gives us that if $X$ is an n-dimensional manifold then $X/G$ is a n-dimensional manifold.

Combining those together, taking $G$ acts PD upon $\mathbb{R}$, I wished to claim that $\mathbb{R}/G$ can't be homeomorphic to $[a,b]$ because we got $\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{R}/G$'s cover, and a covering map is a local homeomorphism then an interior point in $\mathbb{R}$ is mapped into a interior point in $[a,b]$, so $p$ can't map any point to $a,b$. Therefore $\mathbb{R}/G$ can't be homeomorphic $[a,b]$ but all this fail in case we are looking at $[a,b]$ with the induced topology where $a,b$ are interior points.

Am I suppose to observe $[a,b]$ with another topology? or maybe I have a deeper misunderstanding of the concepts I was trying to use? any explanation would be appreciated, also other ways to explain why $\mathbb{R} / G$ can't be homeomorphic to $[a,b]$

Comment: PD = properly discontinuously? And an "inner point" is one contained in the [interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology))?

Comment: @Quasicoherent Yes and Yes, I'll edit to interior points, thanks!

Comment: $\mathcal{T}_\mathbb{R},$ the usual topology for R is a collection of subsets of R.  No element of [a,b] is a subset of R.  Thus their intersection is empty and cannot be a topology for [a,b].

Comment: @WilliamElliot I am not sure I understood you correctly, just as an example to get $[a,b]$ in the induced topology the set: $(a-\varepsilon , b+\varepsilon) \cap [a,b]$ ($\varepsilon > 0)$ is the set $[a,b]$ and is a set in the induced topology.

Comment: $\mathcal{T}_\mathbb{R}\cap[a,b])$  is not a topology because it is empty.   It does not mean the set of open sets intersected by [a,b]. @dan

Comment: all right I'll edit @WilliamElliot